# LibGDX: Why my black/white picture gets transparent?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have another LibGDX Problem (-_-). I have an black/white image like this:

[image]

Now I try to use this image as my background image in my PlayScreen:

Class PlayScreen:

```
(...)
Texture background;
(...)
background = new Texture("grid.jpg");
(...)
gameHandler.getBatch().begin();
gameHandler.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
gameHandler.getBatch().end();
(...)
```

class GameHandler:

```
(...)
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,  1,  1,  1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
this.getScreen().render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
(...)
```

Using this code I get following(wrong scale is because viewport, but that doesn´t matter):

[image]

How can I keep the colors of the real image?

Hope you can help me!
~Henri

Comment: Instantiate your texture with "true" for mip mapping, and set its minFilter to MipMapLinearLinear or MipMapLinearNearest. But it's mostly just going to look gray, because you're shrinking it to fit on screen. If you need a really clean grid and to support devices with varied screen sizes, you need to tile your pattern at runtime by setting your UVs appropriately.

Comment: im doing this right now :D

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with PNG for LibGDX. png images use a raster with pixel-by-pixel accuracy so there is no difference between one png image loading program and another. On the other hand, JPEGs do not contain raw pixel data and are more left up to interpretation.

Comment: In fact, I just found this on wikipedia: "On the other hand, JPEG may not be as well suited for line drawings and other textual or iconic graphics, where the sharp contrasts between adjacent pixels can cause noticeable artifacts. Such images may be better saved in a lossless graphics format such as TIFF, GIF, PNG, or a raw image format. The JPEG standard actually includes a lossless coding mode, but that mode is not supported in most products."

Answer (score 0):

Your image is broken.

Try this:

[image]

Know that i changed path to

```
1.png
```